# How to access GSM modem ports via C++ program

Tags: c++

I want to develop an application where I have to interact with a GSM Modem and require to write AT Commands on the modem via the com port (USB) from a C++ program.

How can I access ports?

Comment: What OS? Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: Use Boost.Asio or the [winapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have to study serial port communication first. not GSM communication...

I've arleady built a c++ serial port class. I'll release the source code on bitbucket soon, or you can download some serial port library
such

[boost::asio (cross-platoform)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) 
[QSerialPort (cross-platoform)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qserialport/)  it'll be part of QT 5.1. 
[CSerialPort (window only)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/382/CSerialPort-v1-03-Serial-Port-Wrapper)

boost::asio is for asyncronous communication, it implements tcp/ip, udp/ip, serialport ecc... Bur require good knowledge of C++ programming.

I suggest you to learn better how serial port communication work. Look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)

Comment: Thanks for the help, plz once you do release the source code, give me the link

Comment: The repository is on the following link: https://bitbucket.org/elvis_dukaj/serialport, This is a very simple implementation that works on window/window ce OS. Next release will also work on *nix

Comment: I've finished all test suite of the project... here you the link: https://bitbucket.org/elvis_dukaj/serialport

Answer (score 2):

If you have the correct driver for your USB device, Windows will show your device as COM port (e.g COM3). You can access the COM port from your code, and manipulate the settings. Your question seems very generic about serial port, so I couldn't be specific. However, here is some help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx ,

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c5425/Serial-Communication-in-Windows.htm

Comment: True. This question is just about communicating with a COM port.

Comment: I want to communicate with USB port of the GSM in order to send sms through it to other cell phones

Comment: Once you've installed the usb driver your os must recognize a virtual serial port (VCP). You have only to open that serial port

Comment: How can I open it plz? I'm new at this.. And once I open it, how can I send sms??

Comment: So you have to study serial port communication first. not GSM communication... I've arleady built a c++ serial port class. I'll release the source code on bitbucket soon.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `CreateFile`, which despite its name will also open COM ports. Just pass the COM port name instead of a filename.

Comment: ok thank you :) and after that do you have any idea how can I send sms through a cell phone connected on this port?